# AngularJS manipulate background-image set in css

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a list which items get a default background image:

```
.defaultListItem > .item-content  {
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url('../images/BGCardboard.png') no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
}
```

Now I want to change the background-image dynamically from my controller.

template:

```
<ion-item class="defaultListItem" ng-repeat="item in items >
     <img ng-src="item.img">
           <div class="itemInfo">
               ....
           </div>
</ion-item>
```

controller:

```
app.controller('home', function($scope, $items){
     $scope.items = $items.getItems();

     //check items, and if there's a background-image, set it to the list
     for(item in items)
          if(item.backgroundImage)
              //manipulate css background-image anyhow
});
```

I don't know how to set the background-image. Any ideas?

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marcelly/WUe2P/14/) you can try out.

Comment: Have you checked out ng-class?

Comment: Not yet, I'll check it out. That's something I could use I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the Ionic Framework, which is fine but adds a layer that's hard to target. (The `.item-content` DIV isn't in your template - it looks like Ionic is providing this...)

But regardless, if you're willing to adjust where in your DOM you need this background image, it's easy to set them in Angular. You can use the ngStyle attribute, or you can just use an expression in the style attribute directly. (There are advantages to both - the expression is simple, but ngStyle lets you do complex things with multiple attributes.)

```
<div style="background-image: url({{ myImageUrl }})"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be what I was after. Going to check that when I get home :-)

Comment: ngStyle doesn't quite work that way. You would need to put the WHOLE style ({ background-image: etc }) into a scope variable, not just the URL. Just use style="". The reason you aren't seeing that work is your Ionic framework is putting a white layer on top. Here's an updated Fiddle that fixes both: http://jsfiddle.net/N93TK/

Comment: would you update the fiddle please, the fiddle at the link doesn't work

Comment: Oh, background color = transparent... that's it. Tyvm... you should add that to your answers.